# How to get the maximum of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x+\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{x+y+z}, x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I know the answer of the current problem, but that doesn't mean I know how to calculate the answer. In fact, I want to know how to get the answer of the general version $(\frac{\lambda_1x+\lambda_2\sqrt{xy}+\lambda_3\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{x+y+z})_\max$.

When $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{z} = 4$, the fraction reaches $\frac43$.
And it's not hard to prove that
\begin{align}
x+y+z &= \frac34x+(\frac3{16}x+\frac34y)+(\frac1{16}x+\frac14y+z)\\
&\geq\frac34(x+\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt[3]{xyz})\\
&\Rightarrow f(x, y, z) \leq \frac43
\end{align}
But how to know that $f(x,y,z)_{\max}=\frac43?$ To be more precisely, applying  Lagrange multiplier method shows that
$$1+\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2x}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{3x} = \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2y}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{3y}  =\frac{\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{3z}$$
how to solve this equation?

Comment: If you've shown that $\frac{4}{3}$ is an upper bound for the function, and that $\frac{4}{3}$ is attained at at least one point, then you've proven that $\frac{4}{3}$ is the maximum by definition. It looks like Lagrange multipliers were not the best method to use here.

Comment: @TheoBendit I know how to prove that $\frac43$ if the maximum, but I don't know how to get it, which mean if a familiar question appears again, I won't be able to solve it by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this system by the following way.

Let $x=a^6$, $y=b^6$ and $z=c^6$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Thus, we have

$$\frac{a^3}{2b^3}+\frac{a^2c^2}{3b^4}=\frac{a^2b^2}{3c^4}$$ and
$$1+\frac{b^3}{2a^3}+\frac{b^2c^2}{3a^4}=\frac{a^2b^2}{3c^4}.$$ 
The first gives 
$$\frac{a}{2b^3}+\frac{c^2}{3b^4}=\frac{b^2}{3c^4}$$ and
$$a=\frac{2b^5}{3c^4}-\frac{2c^2}{3b}=\frac{2(b^6-c^6)}{3bc^4}.$$
Let $b=\sqrt[6]tc$.

Thus,  after substitution $a=\frac{2(t-1)c}{3\sqrt[6]t}$ in the second equation we obtain:
$$1+\frac{\sqrt{t}}{2\left(\frac{2(t-1)}{3\sqrt[6]t}\right)^3}+\frac{\sqrt[3]t}{3\left(\frac{2(t-1)}{3\sqrt[6]t}\right)^4}=\frac{\left(\frac{2(t-1)}{3\sqrt[6]t}\right)^2\sqrt[3]t}{3}$$ or
$$1+\frac{27t}{16(t-1)^3}+\frac{27t}{16(t-1)^4}=\frac{4(t-1)^2}{27}$$ or
$$432(t-1)^4+729t^2=64(t-1)^6$$ or
$$(t-4)(64t^5-128t^4+16t^3+512t^2-313t+92)=0$$ and since
$$64t^5-128t^4+16t^3+512t^2-313t+92>0,$$ we obtain $$t=4$$ and $y=4z.$

Can you end it now?

We'll prove that $$64t^5-128t^4+16t^3+512t^2-313t+92>0.$$
Indeed, we'll replace $t$ on $\frac{t}{2}.$

Thus, we need to prove that
$$4t^5-16t^4+4t^3+256t^2-313t+184>0.$$
Now, by AM-GM
$$4t^5+\frac{1024}{27}t^2\geq3\sqrt[3]{(2t^5)^2\frac{1024}{27}t^2}=16t^4.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4t^3+\left(256-\frac{1024}{27}\right)t^2-313t+192>0,$$ which is true by AM-GM again:
$$4t^3+\left(256-\frac{1024}{27}\right)t^2-313t+192>\left(256-\frac{1024}{27}\right)t^2+192-313t\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\left(256-\frac{1024}{27}\right)t^2\cdot192}-313t=\left(2\sqrt{\left(256-\frac{1024}{27}\right)\cdot192}-313\right)t>0.$$

Comment: How does one obtain that $64k^{30}-128k^{24}+16k^{18}+512k^{12}-313k^6+92>0$?

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut I added something. See now.